# second row of matrix is center aligned instead of left aligned

Tags: amsmath

First time inserting equations directly into LaTeX so no doubt I'm missing the obvious.

I have a simple 2 row, 2 column matrix. However; the top row of the matrix is aligned how i want it to be (left aligned) and the second row seems to have aligned itself centrally. Is there a way to specify alignment for this row?

current result:

[image]

target result:

[image]

markup:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\Large
    \begin{displaymath}
        \Delta\tau_{xy}^{k} = \left\{\begin{matrix} 
        Q/L_k & if\; Agent\; k\; uses\; curve\; xy\; in\; its\; tour\\
        0 & otherwise
    \end{matrix}\right.
\end{displaymath}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Use `cases` from the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dcases*` from `mathtools`. Here the first column is in math mode and second is in text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \Delta\tau_{xy}^{k} =
        \begin{dcases*}
        Q/L_k & if Agent  $k$ uses curve $xy$ in its tour\\
        0     & otherwise
        \end{dcases*}
   \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the same using `cases`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \Delta\tau_{xy}^{k} =
        \begin{cases}
        Q/L_k & \text{if Agent  $k$ uses curve $xy$ in its tour}\\
        0     & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note that in this case, the second column contents needs to be enclosed within `\tex{...}` macro

Answer (score 2):

The `matrix`-related commands of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) all have their columns `c`entred. The easy way out is to use `cases` and friends, or you could set things manually in an `array` with the alignment you desire:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
  \Delta\tau_{xy}^{k} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
    Q/L_k & \text{if Agent~$k$ uses curve~$xy$ in its tour} \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{matrix}\right.
\]

\[
  \Delta\tau_{xy}^{k} = \left\{\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    Q/L_k & \text{if Agent~$k$ uses curve~$xy$ in its tour} \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\]

\end{document}
```